# Are you allowed to pass extra data in a WCF service as part of the post data?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, post, service

I'm trying to send objects which are serialised as JSON to my WCF service. The thing is, though, some of the data from my android isn't needed on the service side, so I didn't add the attributes. I was wondering how I'd be able to have it so it can lack the attributes but still receive it?

So, in my android, I have JSON like this `{"buiildings":{"id":1, "name":"boob", "otherThing":"Ya"}}` and my Building object in WCF only has the **id** and **name** as attributes, so it only expects them. Can I have it so it just ignores the other attribute?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?  You probably could have tried it and found out the results in the time you've been waiting for an answer.  I'm not that familiar with JSON, but depending on what the service expects it's quite possible extra data will be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can pass as many as extra attribute in JSON object. it will not give any error at WCF side. but you are not able to use these extra attribute as it is not define in Building object in WCF.

But i suggest do not to pass extra attribute because it will increase request size, and cause effect on performance.

Comment: Correct! There is a limit on request size but that limit is a large number. So, sending one or two extra objects doesn't have impact on performance.

Comment: I get the error "Endpoint not found" when passed through. Since I have a list of buildings, if it's empty, then it passes through fine. I'm making sure what attributes are used are spelt correctly and in the format that's requested by my WCF service as dictated in the help pages of it (It shows an example of what a request should look like).


It's mainly to make it easier to send, so I don't have to map each value manually and can json the entire object up.

Comment: Seems like it was an error on the server side completely unrelated to this causing the problem. It works fine, now, thanks!